# OpenLayers LineString

Tags: cluster-analysis, relationship, openlayers, multilinestring

I am new to openLayers and would like to know how to simply apply a line from a node to another node to display/identify that each (co-ordinated) node has a relationship (as shown in the image).

[image: example node relationship]

Using Openlayers code version is 7.3.0

I have not tried to implement anything as yet, I've become bogged down with investigation and getting nowhere, peer assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: get the coordinates of the nodes and add a line string to the source like: vectorSource.addFeature(new Feature(new LineString([coordinate1, coordinate2])));